# Static link in WinPE boot.wim not commited when unmount

Tags: windows, winpe, dism

I've created a WinPE iso. When booting it launches my hta application stored in a directory called hta in the boot.wim (windows/hta). Everything works fine. Now, to speed up the development I would like to have a static link in the mounted boot.wim file structure pointing to my checked out hta application folder on a different location. I was expecting the dism unmount commit to copy all the files from the static link and include it in the boot.wim but it's not working.

Does anyone know if this is a limitation within the dism tool or am I doing something wrong? I'm using the mklink to create my static link. I've tried both soft and hard links but without any success. BTW, I'm using the latest Windows 10 ADK.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to make `dism` follow links.  Under most circumstances doing so would break the image, after all.  (I'm not sure about PE.)  From the sounds of it you've mounted the WIM file to a directory path.  You'll need to copy the files into that path, putting a link there won't work.

Comment: Today I'm using batch scripts to copy all by files in to the right places in the mounted boot.wim, but I have to run it every time I make a change to the code. That's why I thought it would be nice to have a static link pointing to my code, then I would always have the latest code when unmounting my boot.wim and building my ISO. Maybe there's a better way to inject the code but WinPE is such a pain to use.

Comment: Even if using a static link worked, you'd still have to run a batch script to rebuild the ISO.  Just embed the copy operations into the same script.